# Undergraduate Real Analysis problem books that do not require Topology

Tags: soft-question, uniform-convergence, book-recommendation, riemann-integration, uniform-continuity

I have seen a lot of suggestions of real analysis textbooks on StackExchange. But unfortunately, because my university course (I am in undergraduate year 2) does not teach Topology before Analysis, the exercises in classics like Rudin and Apostol could be impregnable to me.

Do you have any suggestion of problem books for undergraduate real analysis? They don't need to be dedicated problem books, any book that has many exercises would do. The level of difficulty of the exercises should be at least the level of those in Apostol's "Mathematical analysis". Most importantly, **Topology is not needed to solve the book's problems**.

Here are the topics I want to cover:

1. Riemann integrals: Proving functions are Riemann integrable, and properties of Riemann sums and integrals
2. Uniform continuity & Uniform convergence: Proving functions are uniformly continuous/convergent, and properties of uniformly continuous/convergent functions

Comment: To solve problems in those topics in real analysis you'll need at least a little bit of topology, although it doesn't need to be a whole book or class on topology. Most real analysis books present the topology needed. Have you looked at Rudin's coverage of basic metric space topology for example?

Comment: You can't really do analysis without continuity and compactness which are fundamentally topological properties. I don't imagine there is such a text or if there is I doubt it's any good.

Comment: You can try Jiri Lebl's book. Whether they are challenging problems is up to you. There are also plenty of exercises in Rudin and Apostol which do not require any knowledge of any topological notions.